# Regex to find .pdf or .doc in a file

Tags: regex

I am working with .EML files, these are emails and need to search for certain types of attachments.  In the .EML the file name and extension of the attachment are embedded. here is an example of the string
**Attachment:** Xmas2016 v1.odt

In the above example I want to find .odt as one RegEx then I would also want to find the Xmas2016 V1.odt as a 2nd RegEx where Xmas2016 V1 would be different.

Any ideas?

Tx
Andrew

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this yourself? This is not a drive-by regex writing machine, where you post a somewhat vague description of your requirements and someone churns out a regex for you. We're glad to help, but you need to at least make an attempt to do something yourself first.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you figure it out on your own. I am sure you can do it. Just go through the following articles:

https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/07/regular-expressions/

https://www.talentcookie.com/2015/07/lets-practice-regular-expression/

https://www.talentcookie.com/2016/01/some-useful-regular-expression-terminologies/